# Can Microsoft Exchange Activesync in Knox container still wipe my device

Tags: exchange, samsung-knox, remote-wipe

I set up my work email account (which uses Microsoft Exchange Activesync) on my personal     galaxy s4 (gt-I9505 running 4.4.2) under the Knox container (version 2.0). If the Admin tries to remote wipe my device will it

```
  a: do nothing
  b: wipe the Knox container
  c: wipe my entire phone
```

I've looked around for answers on the web and gotten a few guesses but I would like some proof or at least hear from someone with first hand knowledge.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sent an email to Knox user support:

> I have a galaxy Note 4 with MyKnox installed. I have setup an
>   activesync ms exchange account in the email app. One of the
>   permissions is to allow remote wipe. I know that I have the ability
>   through the MyKnox web portal to remotely wipe my own device. what I
>   want to know is if the MS exchange admin sends a remote wipe command
>   (through exchange, NOT throught the MyKnox portal) will it just wipe
>   the container or the whole device?

Here is the reply:

> Our R&D team has updated that remote wipe command through exchange
>   will only wipe the container if the Exchange account is setup inside
>   the container.
>
> Please let us know if any further queries with respect to this issue
>
> Best regards, Tanuj K Samsung KNOX support

My own addition:

This may only apply to MyKnox and not the other versions. I have friends who work in IT for organizations that use the corporate version and have been told that they can add additional permissions and privileges extending outside the Knox container.

Answer (score 2):

## The Knox container will be wiped.

Knox is a sandboxed instance of Android with its own separate security policy. Exchange's device administrator has no access to the contents of your phone outside of Knox and cannot wipe your personal data.

Comment: That's what I thought and hope for. Do you have any documentation to support your statement or at least personal experience?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what version of KNOX you have or what MDM your company is using.

With My KNOX, a personal version, you can wipe the entire device:

- https://www.samsungknox.com/en/products/my-knox
- https://www.samsungknox.com/en/system/files/admin-doc/Samsung_My_KNOX_Visual_Walkthrough_Guide_14.pdf

With KNOX Premium, an enterprise version, it depends upon the MDM.  Most MDMs can wipe your entire device:

- http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/enterprise-mdm-vendors,2-732.html

Samsung's MDM can be configured to wipe the device or just the container:

- http://www.samsung.com/my/business/mobile/platform/mobile-platform/knox/pdf/MP_Samsung_KNOX2.0_Technical_Whitepaper_V1.0_20140310.pdf
- https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/end-user-devices-security-guidance-samsung-devices-with-knox/end-user-devices-security-guidance-samsung-devices-with-knox

The real answer is:  Go ask your IT department.  Find out who set up the MDM and ask them.

Comment: Knox came pre-installed on my device. The Company IT dept had nothing to do with my setup and doesn't even know I am using it. I am using the mail app inside the knox container to connect to the exchange server. I could have done the exact same thing outside of the knox container. This is not the corporate version.

Comment: It sounds like you have My KNOX installed, and thus you are your own admin.  You can set it up at the "My KNOX User Portal" at my.samsungknox.com, and then you can wipe your own device if need be.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't understand which good content did I really remove in [this suggested edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/91773). Your answer has too many obsolete links, and the sources are scattered and not wrapped under text which looks bad. Are you saying that obsolete links are good content for you? Goodness.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you don't have **My Knox** because if you look at My Knox videos you will see the icon says My Knox.  However, the version you are talking about just says Knox.  I can not find the version support for it either (as I have the same version you do) even though it says Knox 2.3 in the about tab under **my apps** -> **Knox Settings** -> **Knox version**.

Now if you go to the Knox **settings** -> **Device administrators**, you will see exchange sync or email services with the ability to erase data.  The question is when I go to device manager for the personal side of the phone the exchange service (email service does not have permission to erase all data).  I am confused myself. I would suggest that you use an old phone that can use Knox (or not) and use it with wifi only and use the email server only when wifi is available. If they do wipe the phone none of your stuff is on it.  I will carry two phones untill I figure that out.

Centrify is the developer ([Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiKqtq8IhfA&feature=player_detailpage)) and so is the Samsung team.   Let me know what you come up with.  I have missed my password the amount of times required(20 I believe) and it resets the Knox version to new.  There is also this [site](https://www.samsungknox.com/en) for support. Email them as I am now.